# How to run JavaScript after AJAX load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a vertical dropdown or accordion menu run by some js. 
To keep the menu as it is and prevent it from snapping back to it's initial state when some content is loaded I am using a load function.
That seems to work:-) 
But the actual content, an image slider, uses some js as well and when loaded via function the js doesn't trigger, because the entire site is not again. 
How can I re-trigger the js for that content?

This is the load function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#menu2 li ul li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(page + '.php');
       return false;
    })
;});
```

This is the hookup for the slider

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Using default configuration
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel();

    // Using custom configuration
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({

        items               : 1,
        direction           : "left",
        responsive          : false,
        auto : {
            play            : false
        },
        scroll : {
            items           : 1,
            easing          : "swing",  // "elastic", "swing"
            duration        : 500,                         
        },
        prev    : {
            button  : "#p",
            key     : "left"
        },
        next    : {
            button  : "#n",
            key     : "right"
        },               
    });});
```

The js for the slider is called **jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js**.
I guess this and the hookup need to be re-triggered to make the slider work
when only the content was loaded instead of the entire page.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Call $('#carousel').carouFredSel(); from the callback function on the ajax request. Something like this.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

They have a section in their documentation for inserting items into the carousel after it has been initialized:

http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel-advanced#insertitem

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('ul#menu2 li ul li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(page + '.php', function(){
            $('#carousel').carouFredSel({ 
               'insertItem' : $('#content') // Or whatever you need to add 
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#menu2 li ul li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    // Prevents the browser from navigating to wherever the href was leading to

        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(page + '.php', function() {
            // Loads Carousel only after #content has fully loaded
            $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                items               : 1,
                direction           : "left",
                responsive          : false,
                auto : {
                    play            : false
                },
                scroll : {
                    items           : 1,
                    easing          : "swing",  // "elastic", "swing"
                    duration        : 500,                         
                },
                prev    : {
                    button  : "#p",
                    key     : "left"
                },
                next    : {
                    button  : "#n",
                    key     : "right"
                },               
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3517425 You're welcome! Please accept an answer so future viewers will have an easy reference.